# Storm-crawler crawl and indexing

Tags: elasticsearch, web-crawler, nutch, stormcrawler

I've worked with Nutch 1x for crawling websites and using Elasticsearch to index the data. I've come across Storm-crawler recently and like it, especially the streaming nature of it.

Do I have to init and create the mappings for my ES server that Storm-crawler is sending the data to?

With Nutch, as long as I had the ES index up and running, the mapping took care of itself... except for some fine tuning. Is it the same for Stormcrawler? Or do I have to init the index and mapping before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great to hear you like StormCrawler.

As explained in [README](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/external/elasticsearch/README.md) and the [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/xMCuWpPh-4A) based on ES2.x, you should use the [ES_IndexInit](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/external/elasticsearch/ES_IndexInit.sh) script to set the mapping explicitly. It probably works without it but it would not be optimal.

Comment: I'm currently running SC 1.5 with ES 5x. So then can I add more fields to that mapping in the script (for the index index)?

Comment: Instead of using bash script thats included, can I just use Console in Kibana to create the index and mappings?

Comment: you can create the indices and mappings in any way you like, including Kibana. And yes, the mappings are customisable and you can tune it to your needs.